# Touch events on UITableView's backgroundView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, touch

I've got a `UITableViewController`, and the `tableView` has a view as `backgroundView` (even more, it's a `MKMapView`), set with

`self.tableView.backgroundView = _mapView;`

Currently the background view is showing on the screen (I also have a transparent table header to achieve this). I'm not able to make the `mapView` (`tableView`'s `backgroundView`) respond to user interaction. My table header, which is above the map view, is a subclass of UIView with the following override:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    LogDebug(@"Clic en transparent view");
    if (_transparent)
    {
        return nil;
    }
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

so it's supposed to pass through the events; I don't know what's wrong, and didn't find any solution in other similar questions.

I *must* keep the mapView as the tableView's background property, so please take this into account.

Any idea?

Comment: did you got any solution my friend?

Answer (score 2):

it's relatively late to answer the question. But I ran into this problem on my own project, and after some research I got the answer. First off, I didn't assign the view in the back to `tableView.backgroundView`. Instead, I made the `tableView.backgroundColor` transparent then put another view under the table view.

EDIT:
by "under the table" I mean the `tableView` and the `anotherView` are children to the same parent view and `tableView.zPosition` is greater than `anotherView.zPosition`.

Then all I did is override the `tableView`:

`(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

and let the `tableView` avoid holding the events that are not in its cells.

Here's the code:

```
-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    /// the height of the table itself.
    float height = self.bounds.size.height + self.contentOffset.y;
    /// the bounds of the table. 
    /// it's strange that the origin of the table view is actually the top-left of the table.
    CGRect tableBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, height);
    return CGRectContainsPoint(tableBounds, point);

}
```

it works like a charm for me. hope it'll help any other people who run into this problem.

Comment: "then put another view under the table view." can you show the code for that I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the touchEvents cant be passed to tableView's backgroundView.
So, what i did is ,

For headerView  which is a subclass of UIVIEW, i added a class property as mapView.
In **HeaderView.h**

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) UIView *mapView;
```

And, in **tableViewController**

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    HeaderView *view =[[TestView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];
    view.mapView =tableView.backgroundView;
    return view;
}
```

And override hitTest in HeaderView and return this mapView.

```
-(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    return self.mapView;
}
```

Now the mapView receives that touchEvent and responds accordingly.
.Add extra code that you might interest.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Santhu answer almost worked for me, I passed hit test to mapView instead of just returning it, also I needed to made a point check because I wanted only header touch events passing through so there is my version of hit test on the HeaderView:

```
-(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if(point.y > self.frame.size.height){
        return nil;
    }
    return [self.mapView hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a UITableView subclass, the downside is you can no longer tap cells but it hopefully is a pointer in the right direction.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{}
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this is an old post, and UITableView.backgroundView does receive touches now. So, if your content in your backgroundView isn't receiving touches it's due to some other issue.